# Which mysql method is fast?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am saving some text in database say 1000 characters.
But I display only first 200 characters.

**Method 1**

I could save first 200 characters in one column
and the remaining in second column of sql table

**Method 2**

I can save everything in one column and while displaying I can 
query for 200 characters

Comment: Let me rephrase our question: `Guys, can somebody make profiling research on database for my needs?` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be "cleaner" to store everything in 1 column. and you can select only the first 200 characters like this

```
select substring(your_column, 1, 200) as your_column from your_table
```

Comment: And what about productivity? Would it be faster within 10 000 requests per second to invoke DB `substring()` method than simple select one cell?

Comment: `substring` is a pretty fast function. I doubt there are performance issues with this simple function. But I did not try it with such a heavy load.

Comment: Consider google search results, it does something like this. so I think substring() can be used

Answer (score 1):

It really is irrelevant, but if you try to optimize, then method 1 is better, as long as you limit your query to that column (or you only query these columns you really need), because doing any `substring` on server side takes time and resources (times number of requests...). Method 2 is cleaner, but you are optimize for time so method 1.

Answer (score 0):

This will come down to one of two things:

If you are pulling the entire row back into PHP and then only showing the first 200 chars, then your network speed will potentially be a bottleneck on the pulling data back:

If on the other hand you have two columns, you will potentially have a bottleneck at your drive access which fetches the data back to your PHP - longer rows *can* cause a slower access to multiple rows.

This will come down to a server-specific weigh-up. It will really depend on how your server performs. I would suggest running some scenarios where your code tries to pull back a few hundred thousand of each to see how long it takes.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 2.**

First, duplicate storage of data is usually bad (demoralization).  This is certainly true in this case.

Second, it would take longer to write to two tables than one.

Third, you have now made updates and deleted vulnerable to annoying inconsistencies (see #1).

Fourth, unless you are searching the first 200 characters for text, getting data out will be the same for both methods (just select a sub string of the first 200 characters).

Fifth, even if you are searching the first 200 characters, you can index on those, and retrieval speed should be identical.

Sixth, you don't want a database design that limits your UX--what if you need to change to 500 characters?  You'll have a lot of work to do.

This is a very obvious case of what not to do in database design.

reference: as answered by Joe Emison http://www.quora.com/MySQL/Which-mysql-method-is-fast